# Difficulty accessing object property in Javascript from Chrome Extension Downloads API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

The code below is for chrome downloads API from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/f35c32b023487569ba0d9779906b331dd795c829/chrome/common/extensions/api/downloads.idl)

```
dictionary StringDelta {
        DOMString? previous;
        DOMString? current;
    };


[inline_doc] dictionary DownloadDelta {
    //other things
    StringDelta? error; // what i'm trying to access
}
```

I'm trying to make a chrome extension and when I try to access 'downloadDelta.error' as shown below, I get 'undefined'.

```
 chrome.downloads.onChanged.addListener(function(downloadDelta) {
    console.log(downloadDelta.error); 
 }
 );
```

I have no idea what that question mark or DOMString means. The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onChanged) says 'error' is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [question marks in IDL](http://www.chromium.org/blink/webidl#TOC-undefined-and-null) are indicating that all of these things are optionally present just like the API docs you linked to.

For example, `DownloadDelta.error` is `undefined` unless the change that generated it is actually an interrupt that has changed `DownloadItem.error` for the `DownloadItem` indicated by `downloadDelta.id`. A download could have plenty of change events but never set an error or only set it once out of many changes in the state of the `DownloadItem`.

A `DOMString` is a normal (Document Object Model) String, which means the string is appropriate for use by your extension in its JavaScript/HTML/CSS context. The implementation may have access to many other types of Strings in its own language and libraries that may be incompatible.

Since the only thing that is permanent in a `DownloadDelta` is the `id` of the related `DownloadItem`, your onChange callback would normally have two kinds of actions:

1. watch for when specific things like error are defined in the `DownloadDelta` only if you need to react to them once when they change and don't need to consider the rest of the item's download state while doing so.
2. call `chrome.downloads.search({'id':downloadDelta.id}, callback2)` to examine the entire state of the `downloadItem` from `callback2` and take an action that you want to be dependent on multiple aspects of the `downloadItem`'s state that may change independently (and therefore in independent `DownloadDelta`s).

Naturally, you can combine these by examining the delta to selectively setup the search with callback2 only when the delta indicates the possibility that the `DownloadItem` has potentially transitioned to being ready for the action you want to take.